# CCSID error on JDBC Driver Manager java program running on AS400

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to build a simple java program that reads a record from a table in AS400. The program runs in the same AS400. I am getting the following error:

Caught exception: INTERNAL ERROR:  Creation of DB2Driver object for registering with DriverManager failed. -> com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2JDBCDataException: CCSID value is not valid.

The java code snippet in the AS400 is the following:

```
    try {
        
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");            
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:*local", properties);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The exception is thrown at the DriverManager.geConnection method.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does the AS400 have the CCSID set?  `dspsysval qccsid `  If the value is 65535 you need to change it to 37.

Comment: I tried and it is the same result  :(

Comment: ok so the problem got fixed by adding the QIBM_PASE_CCSID to the environment variables. The command is the following:  ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_PASE_CCSID) VALUE(284) in the AS400 command line. I use 284 because the AS400 I work in is in spanish.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question.